# ipython notebook "current directory" in windows

Tags: python, sdk, jupyter-notebook

I am trying out the ebay sdk for python using ipython notebook. I must place a config file, ebay.yaml in the current, home, or /etc directory. Where are any of those directories located in ipython notebook for windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows, it is the directory in which you launched the notebook.  You can always use

```
os.getcwd()
```

if you need to.

Comment: Thanks so much. I have identified the active directory. The thing is I already had the ebay.yaml file there. it's not working and I can't figure out what's wrong. the error I'm getting is "ConnectionConfigError: u'config file ebay.yaml not found'" could a subroutine be calling ebay.yaml in a different directory?